How to convert G1 point to bytes using Rust bn254 crate?
I'm using the following code to generate a signature using bn254 crate in Rust. But it is giving the signature in G1 form. There is a function for Signature called to_compressed but it returns a compressed version of this. I want the the signature to be directly converted to bytes without compressing it.
use bn254::{PrivateKey, PublicKey, ECDSA};

fn main() {
    let private_key_1_bytes = hex::decode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").unwrap();
    let private_key_1 = PrivateKey::try_from(private_key_1_bytes.as_ref()).unwrap();

    let public_key_1 = PublicKey::from_private_key(&private_key_1);
    let message: &[u8] = b"abc";
    let signature_1: Signature = ECDSA::sign(&message, &private_key_1).unwrap();
}

